# Help with PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am working slowly through the PrimeFaces showcase, I am using NetBeans 7.0, JDK1.6, PrimeFaces 2.2.1, GlassFish 3.1, JSF 2.0, Win XP Prof

Some of the examples work fine, others don't work and then I get errors that a component doesnt exist in the library or the component doesn't have a specific attribute. I have **not** done any configuration and the **purchased** very lacking PrimeFaces Manual seemed to suggest I didn't need to

I keep reading about snapshots and am wondering, should I be using a snapshot:

1) Do I need to use this snapshot to get everything to work, if so HOW do I use it?

2) Is there any more documentation / tuts / examples/ books ... of using PrimeFaces components with the above requirements that I have, that have been tested and work.

I have tried other forums but get no response, I would like to eventually develop some apps using PrimeFaces, but can't get the answers or help I need.

Answer (score 0):

On the Primefaces web page there is a "[Showcase 2.2.1](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf)" and a "[Labs Showcase 3.0](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf)". Maybe you tried some features of the Labs Showcase with your 2.2.1 installation?

If not, please give an example of a not working component.

Comment: Thanks!, DragDrop->Data Integration, Google Maps, Image Cropper, BreadCrumb url's, Collector (doesn't), etc

Comment: @user Ok they should work with 2.2.1. Maybe you have an older version of Primefaces lib in you classpath?

Comment: No its definitely 2.2.1, I have now removed it and attached Snapshot 3.0.M2 and installed a theme, this got a few more going but, the others already meantioned, still not. eg: The DrapDrop drags but wont drop into the container, the Collector won't hold more than 1 item, each subsequent item is lost, maybe needs to be static?. The breadcrumb works except I get "For more information visit http://primefaces.org" when I click the link. Before M2, the Charts worked, now they don't, re-attching 2.2.1, they do again, but other stuff stops. ????